# Merging column returned by inner join in sql

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, knex.js

I have two table interest and subint, I want to get data related to every interest so I have tried inner join `select interest,subinterest from interest inner join subint on subint.interest_id = interest.id;` and the result is

```
"interest"  "subinterest"
"foodie"    "tea"
"foodie"    "biryani"
"foodie"    "chocolate"
"foodie"    "cookies"
"foodie"    "fast-food"
"cooking"   "cooking"
```

Is there any way to format my output and make it like

```
"interest"  "subinterest"
"foodie"    "tea"
            "biryani"
            "chocolate"
            "cookies"
            "fast-food"
"cooking"   "cooking"
```

is it possible through any SQL query? or I need to do it by coding.
I want this because I am creating an API using node and knex.js and I want the JSON to be well formatted

```
{
        "interest": "foodie",
        "subinterest": "coffee",
        "subinterest": "tea",
        "subinterest": "biryani"
}
```

Comment: That is not the purpose of SQL. How you format the result is up to coding. Only you have to do in SQL, is to order by the interest column.

Answer (score 1):

Construct the JSON you want in Postgres.  This gives you a JSON record *per row*, which is what I think you want:

```
select row_to_json(i)
from (select interest, array_agg(subinterest) as subinterests
      from t
      group by interest
     ) i;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9cc4c157b88c8198e95b7011a8fa5fa1) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You should try and build an object or array structure like this:

```
arr=[{interest:"foodie",
      subinterest:["tea","biryani","chocolate",
                   "cookies","fast-food"]},    
     {interest:"cooking",
      subinterest:["cooking"]}];
```

*outside* SQL by using some serverside code like PHP, then transport it via a JSON string for "safe consumption" by your knex.js script.

(The above code depicts the *resulting* Javascript array, after JSON parsing.)

Comment: I am trying this approach but I am not able to convert my JSON into the one you have said.This is my json [
    {
        "interest": "foodie",
        "subinterest": "coffee"
    },
    {
        "interest": "foodie",
        "subinterest": "tea"
    },
    {
        "interest": "foodie",
        "subinterest": "biryani"
    }], how can I do it using JS